# FiddlerCore how recognize video streaming

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore

I am trying FiddlerCore for My Proxy , I am facing with the problem on How recognize request to video / file ?

```
            oS.bBufferResponse = true;

            Monitor.Enter(oAllSessions);
            oAllSessions.Add(oS);
            Monitor.Exit(oAllSessions);
```

I want to allow streaming in proxy , in order to do this , seems like i need to set bBufferResponse to false for oSession that tries to stream video. I can't see good way to distinguish video / file requests from html/css/js/img. Any Help appreciated Pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach an event handler to `FiddlerApplication.ResponseHeadersAvailable` and check the `Content-Type` header:

```
string sContentType = oS.oResponse.MIMEType;
if (sContentType.OICStartsWithAny("text/event-stream", "multipart/x-mixed-replace",
    "video/", "audio/", "application/x-mms-framed"))
{
  oS.bBufferResponse = false;
}
```